# Serviço REST dentro de uma Aplicação Web

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security

Tenho uma aplicação web com Spring MVC e existe uma necessidade de um cliente consumir um serviço, criei então no mesmo projeto um recurso mapeado com RestController, ao testar o serviço usando como client o Postman me deparei com um problema, como resposta veio o html da pagina de login e não os dados como json.

No Postman eu configurei a Authorization do tipo Basic informei usuario e senha julguei que com isto estaria tudo ok

Não seria possível ter um recurso Rest na mesma aplicação?

ou teria que fazer alguma configuração especifica no security?

**Atualizado em 01/02/2019**

Passei o dia de ontem estudando sobre o Spring Security e entendi que sim posso criar uma configuração de autenticação para a minha API e quando não a outra pelo formulário de login.
Minha classe de configuração no entanto ainda não ta ok, configurei duas instancias de WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter mais ainda não ta rolando no postman recebo o html do formulário de login.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = AppUserDetailsService.class)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, 
proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //@Autowired
    //private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;    
    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class AppWebConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;      

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring()
             .antMatchers("/resources/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
              .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }   

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/images/**", "/javascripts/**", "/layout/**", "/stylesheets/**", "/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                 .anyRequest().authenticated()
                 .and()
               .formLogin()
                  .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                  .and()
                .logout()
                   .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                   .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/403")
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/login");
            }   

    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin")
            .password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();        
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint(){
            BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new  BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
            entryPoint.setRealmName("admin realm");
            return entryPoint;
        }
    }
```

Aqui o código de um dos recursos que estou expondo

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/produtos")
public class ProdutosResources {

    @Autowired
    private ProdutoService service;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Produto>> listar(){

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).
                body(service.findAll());
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> buscarPorId(@PathVariable Long id){

        Optional<Produto> entidade = service.findById(id);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(entidade);
   }    
}
```

Comment: Que tipo de html é retornado a você? Como está o código do seu endpoint rest?

Comment: Olá Dherik boa tarde, cara quando uso um client para testar no caso o Postman o html retornado é o da pagina de login, pagina esta que deveria apenas ser chamada quando eu estiver acessando o sistema web, sobre o código do endpoint rest vou atualizar a pergunta com ele, e cara obrigado pela interação, pode parecer que não mais alguém comentar já ajuda pode crer.

Comment: Você gostaria de ter um retorno em Json sobre o problema de login, e não um html, correto? Creio que o problema esteja na configuração que fez, colocando `formLogin`.

Comment: Olá boa tarde Dherik, passados estes dias eu não consegui resolver, sei que o normal é ter uma Api Rest e o Client a consumir, neste caso a Aplicação Web veio primeiro portanto quis disponibilizar um recurso na mesma, o que quero simplesmente é quando for consumir o recurso /api/produtos obter o retorno do json referente a ele, e note que no Postman estou enviando no cabeçalho authorizadion do tipo Basic .addHeader("authorization", "Basic YWR......")
então algo não esta configurado corretamente no config mais não sei como.

Comment: Sobre o formLogin Dherik é porque preciso de uma configuração para o sistema Web, pois é um sistema Web que tem um recurso Rest, portanto o lance é acertar uma configuração para Web e outra para a API mais tá difícil, penso que o mais fácil será criar um projeto Rest apenas para este recurso, uma pena então ter dois Tomcat rodando no servidor.